# Spring inbound channel adapter prevent-duplicates=false not working

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have got a problem with the spring inbound channel adapter. Importing new files works perfectly fine.
But the option `prevent-duplicates="false"` does not seem to work properly - when a file with the same name is saved to the specified directory it is not imported.

The definition of the inbound channel adapter:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="batchFilesDemo" directory="#{baseDirectoryDemo}" prevent-duplicates="false"
        filename-regex="^(.*)-(\d+)\.csv" comparator="fileOrderComparator">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Please, share with us the Spring Integration version you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested it with Spring Integration 4.2:

```
<inbound-channel-adapter id="adapterWithRegexPattern"
        directory="d:\tmp\"
        prevent-duplicates="false"
        filename-regex="^.*\.txt">
    <integration:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</inbound-channel-adapter>

<integration:chain input-channel="adapterWithRegexPattern">
    <file-to-string-transformer/>
    <integration:logging-channel-adapter level="FATAL" log-full-message="true"/>
</integration:chain>
```

And my logs look like:

```
[task-scheduler-1] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\1.txt, id=0dc6932a-3007-28bf-41e6-c1d8e3fcc91f, file_name=1.txt, timestamp=1443197583589}]
[task-scheduler-1] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=2, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\2.txt, id=e0f624eb-33b5-297d-7fb9-89904fc01a7a, file_name=2.txt, timestamp=1443197584560}]
[task-scheduler-2] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\1.txt, id=bd680d29-02d9-a5e8-4f8e-c14200315ed0, file_name=1.txt, timestamp=1443197585559}]
[task-scheduler-1] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=2, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\2.txt, id=a4f7d240-5a7b-d088-f987-84f0c747afe0, file_name=2.txt, timestamp=1443197586559}]
[task-scheduler-3] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\1.txt, id=a6a56195-7ed3-01d7-f52f-d08f9b395165, file_name=1.txt, timestamp=1443197587559}]
[task-scheduler-2] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=2, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\2.txt, id=68c95abb-b113-34b1-7488-cf56155845a4, file_name=2.txt, timestamp=1443197588559}]
[task-scheduler-4] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\1.txt, id=a58cab74-bd45-be4c-d7ee-853df5818cfa, file_name=1.txt, timestamp=1443197589560}]
[task-scheduler-1] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=2, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\2.txt, id=a9ba0460-6f37-deed-35ce-03149b23f636, file_name=2.txt, timestamp=1443197590559}]
[task-scheduler-5] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=111111, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\1.txt, id=d6de0d59-1877-e3e8-da21-8f668ec79e72, file_name=1.txt, timestamp=1443197591560}]
[task-scheduler-3] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=2, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\2.txt, id=23b36d87-0d60-0d7a-c2c7-696cf93680f7, file_name=2.txt, timestamp=1443197592559}]
[task-scheduler-6] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=111111, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\1.txt, id=98de0104-2837-6ed1-22a3-1f69292ab5af, file_name=1.txt, timestamp=1443197593559}]
[task-scheduler-2] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=2, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\2.txt, id=d303e0cc-4657-6548-e08e-863b1089528a, file_name=2.txt, timestamp=1443197594559}]
[task-scheduler-7] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=111111, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\1.txt, id=861ffa79-c76d-8216-1620-da50c53bf83c, file_name=1.txt, timestamp=1443197595560}]
[task-scheduler-4] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=2, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\2.txt, id=f63680c5-11c7-e303-9338-9dd5028b7bcb, file_name=2.txt, timestamp=1443197596559}]
[task-scheduler-8] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=111111, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\1.txt, id=7e565984-0dab-6187-5969-2bc9a5104d49, file_name=1.txt, timestamp=1443197597559}]
[task-scheduler-1] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=2, headers={file_originalFile=d:\tmp\2.txt, id=0ae04d1c-a9c9-1877-2025-248c2f387c5a, file_name=2.txt, timestamp=1443197598559}]
```

And so on.

Pay attention that I have there the same two files which are picked up from the directory forever and, please, find how the content of the file `1.txt` has been changed and it is reflected in my application as well.

So, or your `fileOrderComparator` does something unexpected for us. Or your files don't fit the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Artem!

It was indeed my *FileOrderComparator* using a Map to determine the priority of the files by the filename, so similar filenames always prevented the import.

I am using Spring Integration version 4.1.2.